# Doing Nothing More Than Doing "Nothing"

Tags: word-choice

What would be another way of saying "It'll do more harm than good" but in the context of "it'll do nothing for you?" Here's some context.

> The common mistake, however, is believing that only lifting weights
>   multiple times a day will get us to where we want to be. This is
>   **wrong, and unfortunately, it may even do nothing for you**.

I'd like to rephrase this to match and compare like "Nothing more than something" but that sounds really stupid.

Comment: "A common mistake... and unfortunately won't achieve (or accomplish) anything"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps *"This is wrong, and unfortunately, it may even **be counterproductive.**"*

Comment: @user1925224 - You specifically asked for *do nothing* not *do harm*.  How is this a correct answer?

Comment: @jim the question posted is not clear, admittedly, but the OP does state "another way of saying *It'll do more harm than good*."

Comment: @Mari-LouA- OP actually asks for an analog of "doing more harm than good" but for the situation of "doing nothing for you"

Comment: @Jim If an OP could express precisely what they wanted, they'd more than likely not need to ask the question. Sometimes it's necessary to read between the lines a bit, and look for alternatives. It seems I happened to hit the target.

Answer (score 1):

***It will get you nowhere***

is an idiomatic phrase that is often used. In your case you could use:

> This is wrong, and unfortunately, it may even get you nowhere.